# Example of a sequence and topological space such that the sequence has a non-unique limit

Tags: general-topology

In my topology module, we have a lemma that proves Hausdorff spaces have unique limits. I am looking for an example of a space that doesn't have unique limits and an example of a sequence in that space that exhibits this property.

Comment: As this has nothing to do with Hausdorff measure, I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X=\{a,b\}$ with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$ and take the constant sequence $a$. Both $a$ and $b$ are limits of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=\mathbb{N}$ in the cofinite topology ($\emptyset$ is open plus all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that have finite complement). Note that $X$ is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

Let $x_n = n$ as the example sequence.

Then for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ , $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, because any neihghbourhood of $x$ contains all but finitely many points of $X$ and thus of the sequence.